# Reading the desired field from the JSON which is neither JSONobject nor JSONArray in Java and MongoDB Integration

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I want to read the list of friend from the following JSON in java. My java code sample is shown in the post when i execute the below code the error is  either friend is not found or its not array/object. Any help is appreciated. I tried many combinations of the code. For the details the JSON is basically the collection of the Mongodb having one user record.

My JSON:

```
    { 
       "_id":{ 
          "$oid":"5de5266f63b6a8fbb9eb79be"
       },
       "ename":[ 
          "A_Jahoor"
       ],
       "twitter":{ 
          "name":[ 
             "test"
          ],
          "screen_name":[ 
             "Jhoor"
          ],
          "location":[ 
             "islamabad pakistan"
          ],
          "created time":[ 
             "Sat Dec 29 16:55:43 +0000 2012"
          ],
          "language":[ 
             null
          ],
          "friends":{ 
             "name":[ 
                "Bikas",
                "Jebran Khan",
                "Bimal Subedi\ud83c\uddf3\ud83c\uddf5",
                "Web Developer",
                "June Hunt",
                "IJA-ERA",
                "Faseeh Ullah",
                "Engr Lukman",
                "Kamran Ali",
                "Iftikhar Ahmad",
                "Ahmed-i Konevi",
                "tanveer butt",
                "Malik Abrar \ud83c\uddf5\ud83c\uddf0",
                "Engr Waqas",
                "yasir khan"
             ],
             "location":[ 
                "Nepal",
                "",
                "Seoul,South Korea",
                "palandri,Azad Kashmir,Pakistan",
                "",
                "India",
                "",
                "Peshawar, Pakistan",
                "",
                "Islamabad, Pakistan",
                "Istanbul, Turkey",
                "Punjab, Pakistan",
                "Islamabad, Pakistan",
                "Peshawar, Pakistan",
                ""
             ],
             "statuses":[ 
                33,
                85,
                4102,
                1,
                1,
                171,
                9,
                2,
                3,
                38,
                7481,
                234,
                2467,
                17,
                1
             ]
          }
       }
    }
```

My Java Code

```java
String pageName = jsnobject.getJSONObject("_id").getString("$oid");
System.out.println(pageName);
JSONArray arr = jsnobject.getJSONArray("friends");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++) {
    String post_id = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("name");
    System.out.println(post_id);
}
```

Comment: Your structure of friends is not good. You want an array of friend and you did a object with 3 arrays.. the good structure is more something like "friends" : [ {"name":"Bikas", "location": "Nepal", "status" : 33"}, {...}, {...} ... ] if I understood well your problem

Comment: Yes Kamui, I agree, you are right but this structure is coming from MongoDB as it is. I have to process the same JSON. I am interested only in the friends list.

Comment: If you cannot do anything with this structure, then friends is not an array but an object containing 3 arrays. First retrieve a JSONObject, then loop in every array of the object (with keys "name", "location", "statuses") to map each friend value in a proper way

Comment: Ok I am checking it but i need only friends names from this whole JSON.

Comment: then it is even simpler. Just retrieve your JSONObject "friends", then get the JsonArray named "name" of your friends' JSONObject and you're done.

Comment: Kamui, Can i get a sample code of it? When i try with the existing code, the error is that friends not found.

Comment: Because you try to get a JSONArray, not a JSONObject. In JSON, brackets "{" "}" represent an object, "[" "]" an array.

Comment: Thanks Kamui, the following code solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The following code has solved my problem.

```
   String job=((org.bson.Document) it.next()).toJson(); 
               JSONObject jsnobject = new JSONObject(job);
               List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
              // System.out.println(job);
               JSONArray jsonArray = jsnobject.getJSONArray("ename");
               String pageName = jsnobject.getJSONObject("_id").getString("$oid");
              JSONArray syncresponse = jsnobject.getJSONObject("twitter").getJSONArray("name");
              JSONArray syncresponse1 = jsnobject.getJSONObject("twitter").getJSONArray("location");
              JSONObject syncresponse2 = jsnobject.getJSONObject("twitter");
              JSONArray syncresponse3=syncresponse2.getJSONObject("friends").getJSONArray("name");
              System.out.println("User Name:"+syncresponse);
              System.out.println("User Location:"+syncresponse1);
             // System.out.println(syncresponse2);
              System.out.println("User FriendsList:"+syncresponse3);
```